# How to loop DIV and HTML classes in a JSP with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, loops

I want to loop on a JSP that is built programmatically server side.
The JSP displays various number of posts written by users and, for each post, like/unlike buttons.
If the currently connected user has voted like or dislike for a given post, I want to make brighter the corresponding like/dislike button (but this is a detail).

My problem is to loop on the the different "div" and "class" I've created where I store some values integrated with JSTL  statements.

Here is a HTML representation of my JSP (copied from JSBin where I try to create the jQuery loop but without sucess) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <style>
    .like{
      color: green;
    }
    .dislike{
      color: red;
    }
    .thread{
      padding: 5px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 1px;
      margin: 5px;
    }
    .voted{
      border-width: 2px;
      border-color: blue;
      background-color: gold;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="thread" data-post="1" data-vote="0">
    <input type="button" value="Like" class="like"/>
    <input type="button" value="Dislike" class="dislike"/>
    <p class="postId"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="thread" data-post="2" data-vote="1">
    <input type="button" value="Like" class="like"/>
    <input type="button" value="Dislike" class="dislike"/>
    <p class="postId"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="thread" data-post="3" data-vote="0">
    <input type="button" value="Like" class="like"/>
    <input type="button" value="Dislike" class="dislike"/>
    <p class="postId"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="thread" data-post="4" data-vote="-1">
    <input type="button" value="Like" class="like"/>
    <input type="button" value="Dislike" class="dislike"/>
    <p class="postId"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="thread" data-post="5" data-vote="0">
    <input type="button" value="Like" class="like"/>
    <input type="button" value="Dislike" class="dislike"/>
    <p class="postId"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="thread" data-post="6" data-vote="1">
    <input type="button" value="Like" class="like"/>
    <input type="button" value="Dislike" class="dislike"/>
    <p class="postId"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="thread" data-post="7" data-vote="0">
    <input type="button" value="Like" class="like"/>
    <input type="button" value="Dislike" class="dislike"/>
    <p class="postId"></p>
  </div>
  <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

"**data-post**" contains the postId and "**data-vote**" contains the value of the vote by the connected user : 1 = like, -1 = unlike, 0 = unvoted or cleared vote.

Each `<div>` contains a post.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".thread").each(funtion(){
    var val=$($this).data("vote");
    $("p").text(val);
    if(val == 1){
      (".like").addClass(voted);
    }
    else if (val == -1){
      (".dislike").addClass(voted);
    }
  });
});
```

This jQuery funtion doesn't work and I really don't know why. I seem to have syntax error but I don't find it (or them).

Can someone help me make this jQuery run and loop my JSP ?

PS : if anybody knows a JS/jQuery IDE where debugging could be easier and not just "error", it would be nice to give its name.

Comment: Did you notice that you've duplicated the dollar `$` sign within `$(this)` reference? or is it a variable name?

Comment: Yep you're right @Roizpi. It's now corrected but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this snipet.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.thread').each(function () {
    var val = $(this).data("vote");
    $(this).find("p").text(val);
    if (val == 1) {
      $(this).find(".like").addClass('voted');
    }
    else if (val == -1) {
      $(this).find(".dislike").addClass('voted');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.like{
  color: green;
}
.dislike{
  color: red;
}
.thread{
  padding: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.voted{
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: blue;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thread" data-post="1" data-vote="0">
  <input type="button" value="Like" class="like"/>
  <input type="button" value="Dislike" class="dislike"/>
  <p class="postId"></p>
</div>
<div class="thread" data-post="2" data-vote="1">
  <input type="button" value="Like" class="like"/>
  <input type="button" value="Dislike" class="dislike"/>
  <p class="postId"></p>
</div>
<div class="thread" data-post="3" data-vote="0">
  <input type="button" value="Like" class="like"/>
  <input type="button" value="Dislike" class="dislike"/>
  <p class="postId"></p>
</div>
<div class="thread" data-post="4" data-vote="-1">
  <input type="button" value="Like" class="like"/>
  <input type="button" value="Dislike" class="dislike"/>
  <p class="postId"></p>
</div>
<div class="thread" data-post="5" data-vote="0">
  <input type="button" value="Like" class="like"/>
  <input type="button" value="Dislike" class="dislike"/>
  <p class="postId"></p>
</div>
<div class="thread" data-post="6" data-vote="1">
  <input type="button" value="Like" class="like"/>
  <input type="button" value="Dislike" class="dislike"/>
  <p class="postId"></p>
</div>
<div class="thread" data-post="7" data-vote="0">
  <input type="button" value="Like" class="like"/>
  <input type="button" value="Dislike" class="dislike"/>
  <p class="postId"></p>
</div>
```

**YOUR ERRORS**

- Syntax error on line 3 : `$($this)` must be `$(this)`
- To manipulate only the dom inside the current `.thread` element, you should use .find() function of Jquery
- Syntax error on line 6 and line 9: `(".like")` must be `$(".like")` (but you should also use .find())
- Syntax error on line 6 and line 9: `addClass(voted)` must be `addClass('voted')`

Comment: Great @aroniaina !!
Clearly I didn't think about this "find" method at all.
Thanx a lot !!

Comment: You can upvote and accept the answer if it solve your problem!

Comment: Yes I gonna vote for your answer without any problem.
Just tell me one more thing : which tools do you use ?
I personnaly use Eclipse and JSBin, but it's very hard to debug and find my errors (I'm a great beginner in JS).

Comment: My IDE is netbeans, I dont debug it, I saw it with my eyes! but you can use developper tools as `firebug`or `web developper` browser addons.

Comment: Thanx a lot again @aroniaina !
My eyes are still blind yet as I begin with JS and jQuery. Luckilly, I sometimes encounter guys like you who teach me a lot.
Cya.

Comment: Please, tell me one more thing. In the case above, I use a loop with the "each" method, so I can parse all the HTML file once it is loaded and usable.
Each button is drawn  in the order the file is read.
But how can I get (based on the same HTML file) one particular button datas ?
For example, if I click on the third button, I should trigger a function with an onClick event and change the value of the vote and then the color of the button. So how could I know the postID of the button I click on ?

Comment: you can search about jquery .parent() function. here is a link you may read http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing_ancestors.asp

Comment: Yes that's what I did, but The result I get is an array of objects where the "parent" function should give me the wrapping DIV !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127625/discussion-between-aroniaina-and-lovegiver).